# Optical switch for visible light from multiple endoscopes

Tags: camera, multiplexer

This may not be a total fit for the electrical engineering exchange, but its a pretty specific hardware related technical question.

I am interested in multiplexing visible light optical fiber signals. It would actually be endoscopes (not for medical use) that are multiplexed back to a single camera. Each endoscope would get a chance to relay an analog image back to the camera before the next one.

Are there such switches in existence? When I search for optical switches, the results are not surprisingly all about digital optical switches.

A method that would work would be a mirror that is driven by a stepper motor to align the path of a single endoscope

Comment: It's probably easier (and cheaper!) to put a camera on each endoscope and multiplex the resulting video signals.

Comment: I second Mr Tweed's comment. Cameras of suitable capability for this are so plentiful and cheap these days that this should be the method of choice. Goodness - One wouldn't even need to multiplex video signals. Use USB cameras instead and "mux" them via a USB hub to a PC to control the camera sequencing and video snapshot storage.

Comment: No. Expense of equipment is not a factor. Total power consumption is. I cannot use a usb camera. We use a single IP camera which is tethered to a industrial grade modem. Fibre is used to get into explosive environments.

Comment: Can you offer more details on the optical source specs and destination specs? A multiple fiber Mux alignment with inversion would seem to be difficult although there are rotating laser reflectors, I believe they are mounted on granite for accuracy.

Comment: Why is it not possible to use standard coaxial video cable? How does fiber reduce the risk of EOS sparks?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application requires a very specialized (i.e. expensive) CCD, @Dave's answer regarding one camera per fiber and elextrical/software multiplexing is likely the ideal solution.

Another approach would be to use a faceted panospheric mirror (one facet per endoscope) to allow a single image sensor to view all endoscopes simultaneously without the need for moving parts or shutters, though with attendant distortion and resolution issues.

Comment: The degradation in resolution is a serious problem.

Comment: Is there a reason that one camera per fiber won't work?  If cost isn't an issue, use multiple IP cameras and simply enable/disable them via TCP/IP to selectively return images from each endoscope while managing to your upstream bandwidth limitations.

Comment: True, but its difficult to manage power (easier to have one on all the time). Also, total space is an issue.